# Creating a CCLayer with Transparant background color

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating an iPhone application using both `UIKit` and `cocos2d`. Now, in one of my `ViewControllers`, I am adding a `HelloWorldLayer` as a subview. Which is successfully added.

Now this layer is being added with a black background color. I want its background color to be `clearColor`, precisely, I want it to be transparant, so that I can view the contents in my ViewController except for the contents in the `HelloWorldLayer`.

I know how to change the `CCLayer` background color. I am using `ccc4(r, g, b, a)` for it.

Here id my code:

```
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
    if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 128)]) ) {
        CGSize windowSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        CCSprite *imgRoof;
        imgRoof = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Tops.png"];
        imgRoof.position = ccp(windowSize.width/2,windowSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:imgRoof];

        CCAction* action = [CCBlink actionWithDuration:20 blinks:20];
        [imgRoof runAction:action];

    }
    return self;
}
```

I just want to know the color code for `clearColor` for `ccc4()`. Can any one help me please, I am really stuck.

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I didn't find a proper answer to this question, after looking for many docs and searching for days in google, found no proper solution, and no color code is available for `clearColor` for `ccc4` so I used a patch for my application.

I am setting the the same image as a background `CCSprite` to my `HelloWorldLayer`, which I am using in the `ViewController` as a background on which I m adding the `HelloWorldLayer` scene, so that one don't see the black background, and even user presumes that the behind `ViewController` is visible apart from the `HelloWorldLayer` contents.

This is a solution particularly for my application. For other situations, I can't say. If anyone finds any solution to this, please let me know.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
yourView.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor];
```

will do the job for you

Dont forgot

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

EDIT

```
CCLayerColor* colorLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 128)];
[self addChild:colorLayer z:0];
```

The first three numbers are "RGB" colors and the last number is opacity. Each can have a value in range between 0 and 255.

Comment: No it won't as I m adding the layer with cocos2d, and for that I need ccc4 color combination for changing the background color of CCLayer. What u are saying works for UIKit.

Comment: The main view set opaque property to no

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
 CCLayer *pauseLayer;

 CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

 pauseLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor: ccc4(0, 0, 0, 128) width: size.width height: size.height];

 pauseLayer.position = CGPointZero;

 [self addChild: pauseLayer];
```

E.X for using ccc4

```
layerWithColor:ccc4(Red, Green, Blue, Opacity)
```

The first three numbers are "RGB" colors and the last number is opacity. Each can have a value in range between 0 and 255.

Comment: Its giving black background color.

Comment: layerWithColor:ccc4(Red, Green, Blue, Opacity)

Comment: The first three numbers are "RGB" colors and the last number is opacity. Each can have a value in range between 0 and 255.

Comment: Still is there problem try this CCLayerColor* colorLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 128)];

Comment: +(CCScene *) scene
in this method you may be adding a layer in subview and then init method called. in +(CCScene *) scene in which you have declare the layer and after that write this code and then add it to scene. May be this works. layer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 100) width:320 height:480];

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor clearColor];
CGColorRef layerBackgroundColor = [color CGColor];
[subLayer setBackgroundColor:layerBackgroundColor];
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, but I m working with cocos2d, this is a code for our normal view controller layer, which is UIKit